# Is there a way to search for a file by name on node.js

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I want to search for files in specific bucket (Thousands of files) by its name.

I achieved doing that using **gsutil**

```
gsutil ls gs://bucket-name/**name.json
```

but in the GCS [npm library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/storage) I found only **getFiles** function which only let me list files if I only know the directory/prefix but here I want to search for the whole bucket so is there a way to do that

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API does not support searching for a suffix. Behind the scenes `gsutil ls gs://bucket-name/**name.json` is listing the entire bucket and then filtering in the client for objects with name ending `name.json`.

You can do this with `getFiles`, just leave `prefix` and `delimiter` unset.

If you have a very large bucket this may take up a large amount of memory, this can be mitigated by manual pagination or with `getFilesStream`. It will still take a long time, but that is unavoidable.

Code to do this could look like:

```js
    const [files] = await storage.bucket("bucket-name").getFiles();
    files.forEach(file => {
      if(file.name.endsWith("name.json") {
        // do stuff
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: but the execution time difference is very high
`gsutil ls gs://bucket-name/**name.json` takes only 2.283 seconds while getFiles takes about 57 seconds

Comment: You can use `gsutil -DD ls ...` to verify that behind the scenes gsutil is listing everything. You will have to do profiling of your javascript to find out why it is so slow.